# How does a game engine that models objects as "collections of components" work at runtime?

Tags: components, composition

I'm writing a lightweight game engine and while doing some research for it I've come across a number of compelling articles advocating the implementation of Game Objects through a "collection of components" model rather than an "inheiritance from concrete classes" model.  There are lots of advantages:

- objects can be composed using data
  driven design techniques, allowing
  designers to come up with new
  objects without involving a
  programmer;
- there tend to be fewer source file
  dependencies, allowing code to be
  compiled faster;
- the engine as a whole becomes more
  general;
- unforseen consequences of having to
  change concrete classes high up the
  inheiritance hierarchy can be
  avoided;
- and so on.

But there are parts of the system that remain opaque.  Primarily among these is how components of the same object communicate with each other.  For example, let's say an object that models a bullet in game is implemented in terms of these components:

- a bit of geometry for visual
  representation
- a position in the world
- a volume used for collision with
  other objects
- other things

At render time the geometry has to know its position in the world in order to display correctly, but how does it find that position among all its sibling components in the object?  And at update time, how does the collision volume find the object's position in the world in order to test for its intersection with other objects?

I guess my question can be boiled down to this:  Okay, we have objects that are composed of a number of components that each implement a bit of functionality.  What is the best way for this to work at runtime?

Comment: This is a great question, and while I've read around this topic a lot myself, I would love someone to post the definitive answer!

Comment: I have been reading a lot about this the last few weeks, Game Programming Gems #6 has a pretty good article about this... but no good run time example. I still would like to know, how can you manage multiple visual components inside the Game Entity (for a visual game entity family , you could have Particle System component, a weapon Component, and the Character model component), and all of those components inside the same Game Object. How can you manage them ?

Answer (score 1):

Composable architectures usually rely on interfaces. A component then is implementation+data, enabling designers to re-use available implementations with different data. e.g. using the rocket code once with a rocket graphic and once with an arrow graphic. The flexibility comes from being able to "configure" such combinations outside of the actual run-time.

Within the run-time, the objects receive and provide the necessary information via the interfaces. For example, an object would receive an origin and a reference direction to position itself in the world. For actually drawing stuff I'd presume that a kind of graphical context would be passed around and the infrastructure takes care of aligning the default offset/projection appropriately for the current object.

Answer (score 1):

Another great reason for pursuing this strategy is the ability to compose the behaviour of an object from behaviour components, allowing you to re-use behaviours across multiple game objects.

So, for example, you have a basic game object class with these properties: **burnable**, **movable**, **alive**. By default each holds a reference to null. If you want to make your object be burnable, set:

```
object.burnable = new Burnable(object);
```

Now, any time you want to burn an object, use:

```
if (object.burnable != null)
{
   object.burnable.burn();
}
```

And the burnable behaviour will modify the game object in whatever way you desire.

Comment: I'd make Burnable into a functor (implement operator() rather than a burn() method), so you could just say object.burnable();  (And then rename burnable to burn)  I'd also make it so that object.burn by default holds a no-op functor, so your client doesn't need to check if it's null, first.

Comment: What if inside burnable you also wanted to hold some variables like how flammable it is, how long will it burn for, etc? Could they still go in a "burn" object?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen (and tried) several ways to implement this:

1) Components don't exist in a vacuum, but are collected in an "entity" (or "game object") object. All components have a link back to their entity, so your collision may do something like GetEntity()->GetComponent("Position")->GetCoords() (possibly checking for null vectors etc. - the details depend of the language you're working in).

In this case, it can sometimes be convenient to put some common information directly in the entity (the position, a unique ID, "active/inactive" status) - there's a tradeoff between making something "pure" and generic, and making something quick and efficient.

2) There is no entity, only components (I'm using this for my own lightweight game engine). In this case, components have to be explicitly linked to other components, so maybe your "collision" and "graphics" will keep a pointer to "position".

Comment: @emile: In your opinnion, What would be the best way. Pure Agregation? or a hybrid model. I would love to see a good "article" about this subject

Answer (score 1):

I've always found [Kyle Wilson's blog](http://gamearchitect.net/) to be an interesting source from someone who works with this and seems to give it a lot of thought. Especially this entry might be of interest: http://gamearchitect.net/2008/06/01/an-anatomy-of-despair-aggregation-over-inheritance/. It's not the key point of the article but basically what he says is that they (while developing '[Fracture](http://www.lucasarts.com/games/fracture/)') had separate hierarchies. One for GameObjects and a SceneGraph for the visual representation. Personally I think that's a very sound design but I'm not an expert in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible to give the objects a reference back to the Game object?

This would allow the finding of the world position by going back to the Game object then drilling down to the world position.

Comment: This sounds like a nice easy way to go (see my example) - I wonder if there is another way though?

Answer (score 0):

I am researching this also and came up with some solutions that can both be fast and non-intrusive.

The purpose of having component based application is that you can add and remove components whenever you want in runtime and to have little or no coupling; components can coexist without even knowing about each other.

So, how will a "render" component know where it should render or worse, what should it render?
My answer is that each sibling component have access to a shared table of proprerties held by their container (usually the game entity or game object)

For example, suppose a game object with movement component, render component and character component

The render components asks its container for a property named "positionx", "positiony" and "positionz" (if its a 3D game), and then asks for a "rendermodel" property. Based on those, the renderer components render the property returned by rendermodel at positionx, positiony, and positionz. The positioning properties are changed by the movement component, which itself asks for a "speed" property on the container, which in turn is adjusted by the character component based on keyboard input.

If those properties does not exists, they are created at the moment they're requested and initialzied with a valid value (e.g: 0).

In my point of view, components should never query for other component, as they must be seen as generic as possible.

Comment: That was actually a solution that my team implemented in a small project.  At first it worked as you suggested, being simple and flexible.  Unfortunately, as the project matured the table of properties got bigger and bigger and the system got really slow.  I'm happy to have a place to share our findings though.  :)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds a little over-engineered; what do you gain by making location an abstract component of an object instead of a fundamental property?

But if you really want to do it that way, I guess you could set up a dependancy-graph where everything's explicitly connected. So the (eg) collision-volume has a location input that's hooked up to the position-component's output. Take a look at the internals of Maya to get an idea of how this can work.

But again, IMHO this looks a lot like overkill.